# how to represent a JSON as a case class

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I want to represent a JSON as a case class.

```
{
result:"success" or "fail"
message: "some message"
}
```

My particular requirement is that `result` should only take values "success" or "error". Any other value should fail parsing of the JSON

I tried creating a trait and then sub-classing it but I don't understand how to restrict the values of `result`

```
sealed trait JSONResult 

case class JSONResultError(final val result:String="error") extends JSONResult
case class JSONResultSuccess(final val result:String="success") extends JSONResult

case class JsonMessages (
                        result: JSONResult,
                        message: String
                        )
```

Though I could create a variable of type JsonMEssages, I cannot distinguish whether result is of type `JSONResultSuccess` or `JSONResultError`.

```
scala> val jm = JsonMessages(JSONResultError(),"some error message")
jm: JsonMessages = JsonMessages(JSONResultError(error),some error message)

scala>scala> jm.result.result //this doesn't work because result is of type JSONResult which hasn't got `result` though it holds object of type `JSONResultError`
<console>:13: error: value result is not a member of JSONResult
       jm.result.result
                 ^

scala> jm.result
res17: JSONResult = JSONResultError(error)
```

Eventually, I would like to be able to create a `Reads` or `Writes` as follows but I am not confident that this would work.

```
object JSONMessagesImplicits {

  /*Writes (write to JsValue) are used by toJson method of Json object to convert data (say the model) to JsValue*/

  implicit val JsonResultErrorWrites: Writes[JSONResultError] = (JsPath \ "result").write[String](unlift(JSONResultError.unapply))
  implicit val JsonResultSuccessWrites: Writes[JSONResultSuccess] = (JsPath \ "result").write[String](unlift(JSONResultError.unapply))

  implicit val JsonMessagesWithErrorWrites: Writes[JsonMessages] = (
    (JsPath \ "result").write[JSONResultError] and
      (JsPath \ "message").write[String]) (unlift(JsonMessages.unapply))

  implicit val JsonMessagesWithSuccessWrites: Writes[JsonMessages] = (
    (JsPath \ "result").write[JSONResultSuccess] and
      (JsPath \ "message").write[String]) (unlift(JsonMessages.unapply))
}
```

Comment: Property `result:String` doesnt make sense to me

Comment: sorry, didnt understand your comment. Do you mean what would `result` contain in the JSON? It would be either `success`  or `fail`. For illustration, I have mentioned both of them in the above example. It would be either `result:success` or `result:fail`

Comment: Why adding a property that represents exactly the same distinction as the type itself ...

Comment: my approach could be incorrect, thus I have asked the question on SO. The problem statement is that `result` in json should either take `success` or `failure`. Any other value should not parse. Is it possible to do and how?

Comment: Such validation must be done before initializing either one or the other class, an must not be represented by a constructor parameter value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit: `JSONResult` does not know about the `result` field, so it cannot be serialized properly.

`JSONResult` does not have to be a `trait`, it is still possible to transform it into an abstract class and the problem should be solved, for example:

```
sealed abstract class JsonResult(val result: String)

case class JsonResultSuccess(override val result: String = "success") extends JsonResult(result)
case class JsonResultError(override val result: String = "error") extends JsonResult(result)

case class JsonMessage(val result: JsonResult, val message: String)
```

And then, there is no need to create separate `Write`s for everything, it can be shortened to this one:

```
implicit val resultWrites = new Writes[JsonMessage] {
  override def writes(message: JsonMessage) : JsValue = {
    Json.obj(
      "result" -> message.result.result,
      "message" -> message.message
    )
  }
}
```

---

*Update*

If you still want/have to use the approach to define `Writes` with functional syntax, there is still some room for simplification.

I think that creating `JSONResult` entity only to wrap "error" or "success" strings is a bit of overkill, it complicates the further mappings as you see it with the multiple `Writes` in the original question.

We could imagine the sealed stuff as follows:

```
sealed abstract class JsonMessage(val result: String, val message: String)

case class JsonResultSuccess(override val message: String) extends JsonMessage("success", message)
case class JsonResultFailure(override val message: String) extends JsonMessage("failure", message)
```

Yes, the `message` field now comes together with `result` at root level; `result` values are constants in the descendants.

We'll also need to implement `unapply` fo `JsonMessage`:

```
object JsonMessage {

  def unapply(jsonMessage: JsonMessage): Option[(String, String)] = {
    if (jsonMessage == null) None
    else Some((jsonMessage.result, jsonMessage.message))
  }

}
```

After these changes, we have only one `Writes` to define using the original style:

```
implicit val messageWrites: Writes[JsonMessage] =
  ((JsPath \ "result").write[String] and
   (JsPath \ "message").write[String]) (unlift(JsonMessage.unapply))
```

Hope this helps.

*End-of-update*

Comment: I understand your answer. How could I write the same logic using `implicit val JsonMessageWrites: Writes[JsonMessage ] = (
    (JsPath \ "result").write[JsonResult] and
      (JsPath \ "message").write[String]) (unlift(JsonMessage .unapply))`. To `Write` `JsonResult`, I thought I could do `implicit val JsonResultWrites: Writes[JsonResult] = (JsPath \ "result").write[String] (unlift(JsonResult.unapply))` but the IDE is complaining that it cannot find `write`. Also, I suppose my logic will  `{result: {result:success}` which is not what I want

Comment: I can see that in your approach, you use `write(t:T)` while I am just using `write` but I am unable to figure out how to use `write(t:T)` in my approach.

Comment: It worked. thanks. I am wondering why you had to use `unlift` though. I couldn't find a decent explanation of what `unlift` does (though I could understand what `lift` does). Are you converting the return of the`unapply` method from `Option[T]` to `T` so that it maps to `String` arguments of `(JsPath \ "result).write`?